# VBA User Form Range to Variable- Syntax Issue

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I've created a VBA Userform in Excel, where the user selects several ranges. Within the user form, I have input validation through a series of If then MsgBox statements.

As part of this, I need to take the inputted range and use it as a variable.

Assuming that the range is Me.ActDurations, I tried to use this:

```
dim ActDur as range
set ActDur = Me.ActDurations
```

I've also tried:

```
set ActDur = Me.ActDurations.Value
```

And that doesn't work either. What is the proper syntax for this? Using the first type gives me a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Value` property of `RefEdit` returns a string. To use it as a range, you should use the string as a range name. Sample code below.

```
Dim address as String
Dim targetRange As Range

address = RefEdit1.Value 'String returned by the selected range using RefEdit.
Set targetRange = Range(address)

'Do some code here.
```

Modify as necessary for your code. ;)

Comment: Worth noting, `RefEdit` value _will_ include a sheet name, and _may_ include a workbook name, in the form `'[Workbook Name.extn]Worksheet Name'!RangeAddress`.  If it includes a workbook name, the answer will not work (works fine without workbook name)

Comment: @chris: This is something I'm wary of as well, which is why I personally don't go the `RefEdit` option if I can avoid it (too much maintenance over one simple value, tbh). However, what I provided should point OP to the right direction. Thanks for pointing out such an important note, though! +1

Comment: Awesome, works for me! The assignment I'm completing requires me to use RefEdit, normally I'd avoid it like the plague. Thanks!